# Usage of て-form in this sentence (Combining verb and adjective)

Tags: て-form

I came across this sentence,

星が光って、綺麗です

To my understanding, て form is usually used to link multiple actions or talk about multiple states. How does the て form work in this sentence with an adjective and verb?

Answer (score 1):

The te-form has many uses, and in this case this is [te-form for cause or reason](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/te-form-cause-reason.html). Here, 星が光る is the reason why the speaker thought 綺麗. The "result/effect" part can be a verb or an adjective.